# Django endless pagination loads entire data on Scroll

Tags: jquery, django, pagination, django-endless-pagination

I am trying to use django-endless pagination to paginate my queryset.But while scrolling it loads complete data.Infact it must load the queryset as according to the scroll as it is going.I gave the additional option for paginateOnScrollMargin : 20 but it doesnt seem to work What can be the issue?

here is the endless script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function paginate(){
        $.endlessPaginate({
        paginateOnScroll: true,
        paginateOnScrollMargin : 20
    });
}
</script>
```

here is the template where the page template is included

```
<div class="productgrid">
    {% if page_template %}

    {% include page_template %}

    {% endif %}
</div>
```

here is the page template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load endless %}
{% if queryset %}
{% paginate 4,4 queryset %}         
{% for product in queryset %}
                <div class="prodthumb">
                    <a href = '{{ product.get_absolute_url }}'>
                            {% if product.id in dictionary %}
                            <div class="like-icon" id="like-icon{{product.id}}" onclick="getLike(event, {{ product.id }} , 'True' )"><img src="{% static 'images/wished.png'%}" height="25px"></div>
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="like-icon" id="like-icon{{product.id}}" onclick="getLike(event, {{ product.id }} , 'True' )"><img src="{% static 'images/wish.png'%}" height="25px"></div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="likenotif" id="likenotif{{product.id}}">Please Sign In</div>
                            <div class="prodimg">
                                <img src="{{ product.get_image_url }}" height="350px">
                            </div>
                        <div class="quickview">
                            <a href="#qwmodal{{product.id}}" data-toggle="modal" onclick="sendProduct(event, {{ product.id }})">QUICK VIEW</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="proddetails">
                            <div class="prodtitle"> {{ product.brand }} {{ product.title }}</div>
                            <div class="prodprice">
                            {% if product.discount %}
                                <div class="totalprice">
                                Rs. {{ product.get_sales_price }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="discprice">Rs. {{ product.price }}</div>
                                <div class="disc">{{ product.discount }}%</div>
                                {% else %}
                                <div class="totalprice">
                                Rs. {{ product.price }}
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <div id="qwmodal{{product.id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content" style="width:900px; height:550px;background-color: white;border-radius: 0px;text-align:center;margin-top:10%; margin-left:-22%">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="   Close" style="width:0px; opacity: 0.6; color:black!important; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 24px;">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                  </div>
                                    <div class="leftpart">
                                        <div id="main" role="main">
                                          <section class="slider">
                                            <div class="flexslider">
                                              <ul class="slides">
                                                    {% for image in product.productimage_set.all %}
                                                    <li>
                                                    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" height="100%"/>
                                                    </li>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                          </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                        <div class="rightpart"> 

                        <div class="brandlogo">
                            {% for image in product.brand.brandimages.logo %}
                                 <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" height="40px" />
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>  

                        <div class="prodtitle pull-left">{{ product.title }}</div>

                    <div class="price-mod pull-left">
                        <div class="pricebox" id="pricebox">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="size-mod">
                <span id="smgreytx" style="line-height: 2; float:left">SIZE</span>
                    <ul style="margin-left:50px">
                        <div id="sizes">
                        </div>
                        <div id="selectsize" style="display:none"><span>Please select Size</span></div>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="like">
                        <span type="submit" class="likealign" id="likebtn{{product.id}}" onclick="getLike(event, {{ product.id }} , 'True' )">
                        {% if product.id in dictionary %}
                        <img src="{% static 'images/wished.png'%}" height="30px" id="likeimg" class="pull-left"> Liked
                        {% else %}
                        <img src="{% static 'images/wish.png'%}" height="30px" id="likeimg" class="pull-left"> Like
                        {% endif %}
                        </span>
                        <div class="likenotifmod" id="likenotifmod{{product.id}}">Please Sign In</div>

                </div>
                <div id="soldby">
                </div>

                <div class="action">
                <div id="addbutton">
                <button class="button" type="Submit" id="addtocart" onclick="getCart(event, {{ minId }} )">ADD TO BAG</button>
                </div>
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}"><button class="button" type="Submit">VIEW DETAILS</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% show_more "show more" %}
```

How can i make the endless pagination to load data when scroll reaches the bottom of the page?

Comment: So you want a page by page pagination?

Comment: i want to load queryset according to scroll

Comment: scroll margin is not working somehow

Comment: multiple requests are sent on scrolling